# worksheet cell value change for a loop of cells

Tags: excel, vba

So i am currently using a classic "Run macro if Cell changes value":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("O1"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Call Macro A
End if
End Sub
```

Now i want to extend the macro so it checks every cell in the range `Range("O1:O40")`, and run a different macro depending on which cell that changes value.
The different macros could be placed in a loop, as the code is essentially:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("O1"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Worksheets("Data").Range("N1").Value = Worksheets("Input").Range("O1").Value
ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(Range("O2"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Worksheets("Data").Range("N2").Value = Worksheets("Input").Range("O2").Value
End if
End Sub
```

so if `Worksheets("Input").Range("O1")` changes value, the value must be copied to `Worksheets("Data").Range("N1")`, and so forth for all the cells in range `"O1:O40"`

Comment: And what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run through the range using a For Each Loop

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("O1:O40")
    If Not Application.Intersect(cell, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Data").Range("N" & cell.row).Value2 = cell.Value2
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what i was looking for. Thanks alot.